# Not able to close a UiApp after it is invoked as a published service

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a published service on my script, the link to which I pass out to an email. Once the active account invokes the service a UiApp opens up for further processing. I do that using doGet(). Once the processing on the UiApp is complete I have a Submit button, linked to a server click handler, which is supposed to process the changes made through the UiApp forms. While I am able to change the values on the spreadsheet that I wish to change using this UiApp, I still have two issues which I encounter on clicking the Submit button:

1. The Ui App doesn't close on pressing the submit button
2. I am not able to call a browser msgBox to give a process complete verification message.

I have read a lot that on closing and returning the app the UiApp is supposed to get closed, but it isn't happening and I am assuming this is because that happens only if there is no serverClickHandler involved. I could be wrong.

Can someone help me with resolving Issue 1 and getting around Issue 2? A relevant version of my doGet and clickHandler functions are attached below.

```
function doGet(e) //On invoking service in the mail.
{
  //Adding all other elements of the UiApp here
  /* …
     …  All other elements of the UiApp
     …
*/
  //Adding Submit button to the UiApp
  var button = app.createButton('Submit');
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('click').addCallbackElement(panel);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);
  panel.add(button);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

 function click(eventInfo) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 //Processing the actions that have to be performed on hitting the submit button
/* …
   … Processing the actions that have to be performed on hitting the submit button
   …
*/
   app.close();
   return app;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser.messageBox are not available in published UiApps, you should use a label that is invisible until you make it visible at the end of the process.
The other issue is not an issue neither : The UiApp have no way to close your browser window, you could simply make the main panel of your UI invisible.

Combining both modifications will allow you to hide your form and to replace it by a 'completed, thanks for submitting' message.